# Kenburn zoom image effect doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css

I need to zoom image with Kenburns effect by clicking. This doesn't work, however.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('.kenburns').on('click', function () {

    $('.kenburns').addclass('img.zoom');
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ramswarnak/PABgx/7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jQuery code has a few issues:

First, `addclass` should be `addClass`. Javascript is case-sensitive.

Second, the element `addClass` is attached to is for the parent div, not the image itself. Essentially you were trying to apply the CSS transform to the div instead of the image, while you actually want to apply it to the image. To add the class to the image and not the parent div, use as your selector:

```
$('.kenburns img')
```

instead of ...

```
$('.kenburns')
```

Alternatively, and perhaps more performantly, you can use

```
$('.kenburns').children('img')
```

Finally, the class name you were trying to add to the image is incorrect. `addClass` accepts the CSS class name ("zoom"), not the CSS selector ("img.zoom").

Corrected code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.kenburns').on('click', function () {
        $('.kenburns img').addClass('zoom');
    });
});
```

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PABgx/8/)

Comment: thanks for the help. can you please tell me if this image is background image on website, when i click another div how to change this coad.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You might want to make another question Stack Overflow, providing a link to this question, asking your new one. It's a lot easier to answer that way, and the answer could helps others in the future.